# How to find all items in a list where a property has a specific value or where there is a related item with this value?

Tags: c#, linq, list

How to get(or filter) list where there are record with the same userID and artistID

Here is my rating object

```
public class Rating
{
    public int userID { get; set; }
    public int artistID { get; set; }
    public int rating { get; set; }
}
```

and here is my data

```
Rating rate1 = new Rating { artistID = 1, userID = 101, rating = 2 };
Rating rate2 = new Rating { artistID = 1, userID = 102, rating = 4 };
Rating rate3 = new Rating { artistID = 2, userID = 101, rating = 3 };
Rating rate4 = new Rating { artistID = 2, userID = 102, rating = 5 };
Rating rate5 = new Rating { artistID = 3, userID = 102, rating = 1 };

List<Rating> ratings = new List<Rating>(2);
ratings.Add(rate1);
ratings.Add(rate2);
ratings.Add(rate3);
ratings.Add(rate4);
ratings.Add(rate5);
```

Output if there ara record : 
where userID = 101, and 
where (artistID where userID is 101)

Output example that i want to have:

```
artistID    userID      rating
1           101         2
1           102         4
2           101         3
2           102         5
```

I want also `1, 102, 4` because there is another rating with this `artistID` which userID is 101. The same applies to `2, 102, 5`.

**Update**
If You want to **include all records where there is another record with a different user but the same artist** (quote from @Tim Schmelter). You can found answer from @Tim Schmelter in **Update** version.

For example, if u change rate5 to `Rating rate5 = new Rating { artistID = 3, userID = 101, rating = 1 };` and also add new object rate6 `Rating rate6 = new Rating { artistID = 3, userID = 102, rating = 1 };`

It will make result:

```
artistID    userID      rating
1           101         2
1           102         4
2           101         3
2           102         5
3           101         1
3           102         1
```

Because artistID that rated by userID-101 also rated by userid-102
you can found answer in @Tim Schmelter answer.

Comment: Good start but the crux is not very clear to me: *"Output if there ara record : where userID = 101, and where (artistID where userID is 101)"*. Could you please elaborate or put another way?

Comment: @OP: i have edited your question to clarify the requirement. If that was not correct feel free to edit it again.

Answer (score 4):

So you want all ratings where either the `userID` is 101 or there is one with the same `artistID` that has `userID` = 101? You can use `Any` in `Where`:

```
var query = ratings.Where(r =>  r.userID  == 101 || 
              ratings.Any(rr => rr.userID == 101 && r.artistID == rr.artistID));
```

This is similar to a correlated subquery in sql.

Test:

```
foreach (Rating r in query)
    Console.WriteLine("artistID = {0}, userID = {1}, rating = {2}"
                   , r.artistID, r.userID, r.rating);
```

Result:

```
artistID = 1, userID = 101, rating = 2
artistID = 1, userID = 102, rating = 4
artistID = 2, userID = 101, rating = 3
artistID = 2, userID = 102, rating = 5
```

---

**Update** *"i want all records where there is another record with a different user but  the same artist"*

Now it's clear, you want this:

```
var query = ratings
    .Where(r => ratings
        .Any(rr => r.artistID == rr.artistID && rr.userID != r.userID));
```

Comment: Thank you Tim, I see, so the first 'Where' is to get record where's have specified userID, and the next 'Any' to get artistID where's 101-userID also have. Right?

Comment: @Jusdek: the `Any` is **in** the `Where`, it returns a `bool`. That is what makes them _correlated_. So either this rating's `userID` is already 101 or there is another rating with `userID == 101` with the same `artistID`.

Comment: I see, so `Any` just trigger for other user ID. Then How if we want filter userID 101 which also have rated by other userID. For example change `rate5` item to `Rating rate5 = new Rating { artistID = 3, userID = 101, rating = 1 };` in the output, `rate5` wont show up

Comment: @Jusdek: `Enumerable.Any` is not a _trigger_, `ratings.Any` just checks if there is at least one rating with **that** artistID and userID = 101. If i change rating5 to `new Rating { artistID = 3, userID = 101, rating = 1 }` it will be included in the result. I've checked it. The reason is simple: it has also userID = 101 then. Is that desired?

Comment: I see. No, I dont want it(rate5) included. rate5 only included when there are new object included into ratings example: `Rating rate6 = new Rating { artistID = 3, userID = 102, rating = 1 };` I mean, i want to output record where userID and artistID have pair. rate5 didn't included because no other userID(besides 101) rate this artistID(3), but when we add 1 more record(rate6), it will be included becaause artistID that rated by userID-101 also rated by userid-102.

Comment: @Jusdek: now it's clear. You should also edit your question to clarify it since that is a different requirement. I will edit my answer, wait a moment.

Comment: Thank you that's what I desired. Thank you so much. Sure. Do you have suggestion what title should be? to make others easier to find.

Comment: @Jusdek: i'm glad i could help. Consider to  accept the answer. For the title you could either leave it as it is(since i also answer that) and just add **Update** to your question with the new requirement or change it to what i've used in my **Update**: _"How do i get all records where there is another record with a different user but the same artist?"_